# How can I reference a function with the arguments I want to provide?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code right now.

```
 return_btn = document.getElementById(bkid).querySelector(".returnbtn");
 return_btn.onclick = cancelReturn; // I want to define arguments here
 return_btn.innerHTML = "Cancel"
```

Here, I wish to define the onclick function as `cancelReturn` while providing arguments.
For example in HTML I would write

`<button class="returnbtn" onclick=cancelReturn(bkid)>Cancel</button>`

How can I do something similar in javascript?

Thank you for reading this, I hope you can help me figure this out.

Comment: When an event handler is called, it's the **web browser** that decides what to pass to the function. Now, you can always wrap a call to your function in *another* function, and pass whatever parameters you want.

Comment: `foo.addEventListener("click", function (event) { cancelReturn('whatever'); }` or bind https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to call `cancel_return`

```js
return_btn.onclick = () => cancelReturn(args);
```